# Frequency table by row in R

Tags: r, contingency

This may be a beginner question but I can't find an answer on the webs... maybe because I'm not good at describing the problem.

I want to create a frequency table of nominal data separate by rows. For example, in this matrix:

```
x <- matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 3, 
  c("A","B","B",
  "C","C","B",
 "D","A","B"
  ))
```

Using the table(x) function gives me:

> A B C D
>   2 4 2 1

But I want to obtain separate counts for each row, where the resulting table is:

> A B C D
>   1 2 0 0
>
> 0 1 1 0
>
> 1 1 0 1

I'm sure this is some version of a contingency table but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Your expected output seems to be for each column.  Also, some values are not right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply`, with `MARGIN=1`, to loop through the columns, convert to `factor` with `levels` specified as `unique` elements of 'x', and get the `table`

```
un1 <- sort(unique(c(x)))
t(apply(x, 2, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = un1))))
#     A B C D
#[1,] 1 2 0 0
#[2,] 0 1 2 0
#[3,] 1 1 0 1
```

---

Or use a vectorized approach

```
table(c(col(x)), c(x))
#    A B C D
#  1 1 2 0 0
#  2 0 1 2 0
#  3 1 1 0 1
```